# Changing label in checkout page of ecommerce addon, Concrete5

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, concrete5

how can i change the labels in the checkout page in the eCommerce of concrete5?

for example the label is "Address 1". I want to change it to "Address one".

Comment: What u tried here ? show us code pls

Comment: <?php 
   $ak = CoreCommerceOrderAttributeKey::getByHandle('billing_address');
   echo $form_attribute->display($ak, $ak->isOrderAttributeKeyRequired());
   ?>

tried this and it shows the label but I cant control the label

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I haven't used core commerce. But the code you're using makes it look like "normal" concrete5 attributes.

Have you tried to edit the attribute names in the dashboard interface?